# R HTS package: combinef and aggts not working with gts object

Tags: r, hierarchy, forecasting

I'm trying to apply the combinef and aggts functions from the R hts package to a time series matrix in order to obtain an optimized set of forecasts across a hierarchy. I've run the same code every month without issue, and am now seeing errors after upgrading to hts package v4.5.

Reproducible example (I can share data file offline if needed)

```
    #Read in forecast data for all levels of hierarchy#

fcast<-read.csv("SampleHierarchyForecast.csv", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

#Convert to time series#

fcast<-ts(fcast, start = as.numeric(2010.25) + (64)/12, end = as.numeric(2010.25) + (75)/12, f= 12)

#Create time series of only the bottom level of the hierarchy#
index<-c()

fcastBottom<-fcast
for (i in 1:length(fcastBottom [1,]))
{
    if(nchar(colnames(fcastBottom)[i])!=28)
    index[i]<-i
    else
    index[i]<-0
}
fcastBottom<-fcastBottom[,-index]

#Create grouped time series from the bottom level forecast #
GtsForecast <- gts(fcastBottom, characters = list(c(12,12), c(4)), gnames = c("Category", "Item", "Customer", "Category-Customer"))
#Use combinef function to optimally combine the full hierarchy forecast using the groups from the full hierarchy gts#
combo <- combinef(fcast, groups = GtsForecast$groups)
*Warning message:
In mapply(rep, as.list(gnames), times, SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter*
traceback()
2: stop("Argument fcasts requires all the forecasts.")
1: combinef(fcast, groups = GtsForecast$groups)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Example below - I can share the data file offline if needed.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. Please provide a *minimal* reproducible example.

Comment: Hi. Can you please send the data file to me? I'm not able to see what's the problem using the code above. Thanks.

Comment: Earo-- thanks, I've sent you an email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a little bug when `comebinef()` function calls `gts()`. Now I've fixed it on github. So you can run your own code above without any trouble after updating [the development version](https://github.com/robjhyndman/hts).

Alternatively, you need to tweak your code a bit if you don't want to install the newest version.

```
combo <- combinef(fcast, groups = GtsForecast$groups, keep = "bottom")
combo <- ts(combo, start = as.numeric(2010.25) + (64)/12, 
            end = as.numeric(2010.25) + (75)/12, f = 12)
colnames(combo) <- colnames(fcastBottom)
newGtsForecast <- gts(combo, characters = list(c(12,12), c(4)), 
                  gnames = c("Category", "Item", "Customer", 
                             "Category-Customer"))
Aggregate <- aggts(newGtsForecast)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Earo-- the code changes you suggest fixed the issue. Thanks!